# ClassCastException when creating an action

Tags: selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I am simply trying to create an Actions object from the import:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions;
```

The line of code that throws the exception is this:

```
Actions action = new Actions(webdriver);
```

And the full error message is this:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver incompatible with org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions
```

I have no clue why this isn't working. It's relatively straightforward and the code is no different from the various examples of creating Actions objects on this site.

Comment: What is your ChromeDriver and Selenium version. Seems like a compatability issue.

Comment: Chromedriver version 2.37 and Selenium version 3.13

Comment: did you tried cleaning once and removing and importing again?

Comment: Cleaning? Sorry I don't fully understand your instructions @muraliselenium

Comment: forgot to @demouser123 in my other comment

Comment: Please add your code. Class Cast exception means that there is an issue with your casting operations.

Comment: @demouser123 I suspect you're right about the comparability issue, are you not? The code is much too long, but here are the lines that are relevant:   WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(chromeOptions);
Actions action = (Actions) driver;

Comment: cleaning means project clean.

Comment: clean and build your project.

Comment: @muraliselenium I cleaned it and still have the same issue